# How to set text of a TextView using EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Using a text field, how would I set the text of a TextView while constantly updating the text? For example: The user begins to type information into the text field, this changes some text in in the activity they're  in, however, the user does not need to manually update the text, instead the text **automatically** refreshes.

I have tried doing this myself and searched for other dilemmas, yet nothing appears to work. Additionally, I'm working with fragments that could possibly cause the problem. The code is below, partitioned into areas, before `onCreateView()`, in `onCreateView()` and after `onCreateView()`.

**Before** `onCreateView()`:

```
// Edit Text
EditText exerciseOneTitle;

// String value, contains value of exerciseOneTitle
String value;

// titleOne, what I want to the user to be able to change
TextView titleOne;
```

**During** `onCreateView()`:

```
// Edit text
exerciseOneTitle = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_text);

// Get Edit Text value
value = exerciseOneTitle.getText().toString();

// Set title so there is always an initial value
titleOne.setText(R.string.exercise_one);

// Checks if edit text is focused
exerciseOneTitle.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // While edit text is focused, update titleOne via refresh()
        while (hasFocus == true) {
            refresh();
        }
    }
});
```

**After** `onCreateView()`:

```
// Get the updated "value" and set it as titleOne text
// Additionaly, will be using it in other situations
public void refresh() {
    value = exerciseOneTitle.getText().toString();
    titleOne.setText(value);
}
```

Any thoughts or ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TextWatcher.. See the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

According to the docs

> onTextChanged() is called to notify you that, within s, the count
>   characters beginning at start have just replaced old text that had
>   length before. It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from
>   this callback.

Try this..

```
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.charCounts);
    textMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
    textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            tv.setText(textMessage.getText().toString());
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining your answer, link to docs, something so the OP and future visitors can understand why they should use this code?

Comment: Sorry... @OrhanC1 ..Ive edited my answer..